# When I copy and paste code from Microsoft Word or Google Docs into R, I find that the lines do not match up. I am using a Mac. How can I fix this?

Tags: r

When I copy and paste code from Microsoft Word or Google Docs into R, I find that the lines do not match up. Instead of 80+ lines, I might have 45. I am using a Mac. So, when using R studio, I can't see all the code in the window. How can I fix this so the lines match up with how the lines appeared in the original document?

Answer (score 1):

Text can be on two lines for two reasons:

1. The line is long and in Word/GoogleDocs the line "wraps" onto a second line, or
2. A (usually) invisible carriage return explicitly indicates that more text should start on the next line.

In many text editors including RStudio, you can control whether or not you want #1 to occur; that is, RStudio can either wrap a long line or not, in which case you have to scroll to the right to read the rest of the line.

To control this behavior in RStudio, go to **Tools > Global Options > Code**   and then check the box to **"soft-wrap R source files"**